# Variance of time integral of a function on an Ito process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I was struggling a bit with the time integral of an Ito process.

Say I have this:
$$\int^T_t \alpha\circ X_t ds$$
Where $X_t$ is an Ito process, and $\alpha$ is a continuous function. What can we say about the variance and expectation of such a function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not much

$$E\int^T_t \alpha\circ X_s ds=\int^T_t E[\alpha\circ X_s] ds$$

and

$$E(\int^T_t \alpha\circ X_t ds)^{2}=\iint^T_t E[(\alpha\circ X_s)( \alpha\circ X_r)] dsdr.$$

Here you need information about $\alpha$ to proceed further. If you further have L-Lipschitz from the comment, then the expectation is bounded by

$$|E\int^T_t \alpha\circ X_s ds|\leq |\alpha(X_{0})|(T-t)+L \frac{T^{2}-t^{2}}{2}$$

and the second moment by

$$|E(\int^T_t \alpha\circ X_t ds)^{2}|\leq \iint^T_t (|\alpha(X_{0})|+Lr)(|\alpha(X_{0})|+Ls)drds$$

$$=|\alpha(X_{0})|^{2}(T-t)^{2}+2|\alpha(X_{0})|(T-t)L\frac{T^{2}-t^{2}}{2}+L^{2}(\frac{T^{2}-t^{2}}{2})^{2}.$$

Comment: Okay, what if we had that $\alpha$ was Lipschitz?

Comment: then you can get an upper bound using $$\alpha(X_{t})\leq \alpha(X_{0})+Lt$$, but not exact.

Comment: Aaah I see. Thank you!